# Database specificity in sql dump file generated using Ansible mysql_db module

Tags: mysql, ansible

I'm using the Ansible **mysql_db** module to create a sql dump file of a database on a remote server. I'm then downloading this dump file to import into a local database that has a different name.

My issue is that the dump file that the mysql_db module creates is prefixed with the **CREATE DATABASE** and **USE** commands. E.g.:

```
CREATE DATABASE /*!32312 IF NOT EXISTS*/ `remote_db_name` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 */;

USE `remote_db_name`;
```

This is causing issues as, when I try to import this dump into my local database (that has a different name), it's creating a whole new database locally and importing into that instead.

Are there any options you can pass to the Ansible mysql_db module to prevent it adding the CREATE DATABASE and USE commands to the dump file?

Here is the line in my Ansible playbook that creates the sql dump file:

```
mysql_db: state=dump name={{ db_name }} login_user={{ db_user }} login_password={{ db_password }} target=/var/www/{{ domain_name }}/db_backups/{{ db_name }}_{{ dumpdate }}.sql
```

Remote server is running Ubuntu 18.04 with MySQL Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.28 if that makes any difference.

Comment: There are options you can pass to `mysqldump` (i.e. `--no-create-db`) but the ansible module does not seem to support them. So you either need to 1) vote for an evolution ticket if it already exists or create one, 2) create a pull request to add the option to the module 3) create the dump exactly as you need it by calling `mysqldump` yourself through command/shell.

Comment: @Zeitounator - great, I'll try using the standard mysqldump command instead of the mysql_db module. If you put this down as the answer I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transforming comment as answer upon OP's request

---

There is an option you can pass to `mysqldump` (i.e. `--no-create-db`) but the [ansible module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/mysql_db_module.html) does not seem to support it.

So at time of writing this answer (6th of December 2019) you either need to:

1. vote for an evolution ticket if it already exists or create one on the github project
2. create a pull request yourself on the github project to add the option to the module
3. create the dump exactly as you need it by calling `mysqldump`
   yourself through `command` or `shell`